# Update or insert of view or function failed because it contains a derived or constant field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to understand what is wrong with the following view, and unfortunately I was not able to find my answer anywhere, other than using triggers, which I would like to avoid. Given the following view, when I try to insert into it I get the error above, however if I remove the inner join to the Company table everything seems to work just fine:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwCheckBookingToCheck]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  [checkUser].[CheckID] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckToTypeID] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckNumber] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckDate] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckAmount] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckStatusID] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckAcceptedBy] ,
        [checkUser].[CreatedBy] ,
        [checkUser].[CreatedDateTime] ,
        [checkUser].[CheckToUserID] [ToID],
        [checkUser].[CheckFromCompanyID] [FromID],
        [companyFrom].[CompanyName]
FROM    [dbo].[CheckUser] [checkUser]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] [companyFrom] ON [companyFrom].[CompanyID] = [checkUser].[CheckFromCompanyID]

UNION ALL

SELECT  [checkCompany].[CheckID] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckToTypeID] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckNumber] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckDate] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckAmount] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckStatusID] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckAcceptedBy] ,
        [checkCompany].[CreatedBy] ,
        [checkCompany].[CreatedDateTime] ,
        [checkCompany].[CheckToCompanyID] [ToID],
        [checkCompany].[CheckFromCompanyID] [FromID] ,
        [companyFrom].[CompanyName]
FROM    [dbo].[CheckCompany] [checkCompany]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] [companyFrom] ON [companyFrom].[CompanyID] = [checkCompany].[CheckFromCompanyID]

GO
```

Here is my insert, I am only inserting in [CheckUser] or [CheckCompany]:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[vwCheckBookingToCheck]   
    ( [CheckToTypeID] ,
      [CheckNumber] ,
      [CheckDate] ,
      [CheckAmount] ,
      [CheckStatusID] ,
      [CheckAcceptedBy] ,
      [CreatedBy] ,
      [CreatedDateTime] ,
      [ToID] ,
      [FromID] 
    )
     SELECT 2,
      'Test' , -- CheckNumber - varchar(255)
      '2014-08-23 20:07:42' , -- CheckDate - date
      1233 , -- CheckAmount - money
      0 , -- CheckStatusID - int
      1 , -- CheckAcceptedBy - int
      1 , -- CreatedBy - int
      '2014-08-23 20:07:42' , -- CreatedDateTime - datetime
      1,  -- ToID - int
      1  -- FromID - int
```

CheckToTypeID is my check constraint, is there any way to make this view work with inner joins? Again, if I remove the inner joins I am able to get it to work, but I would like to keep them if possible.

I am using SQL Server 2012, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I cannot readily find the 2012 documentation on this subject, but the [SQL Server 2008 documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187067(v=sql.105).aspx) says:

> A view is considered an updatable partitioned view when the view is a
> set of SELECT statements whose individual result sets are combined
> into one using the UNION ALL statement. **Each SELECT statement
> references one SQL Server base table.**

You have two tables in the `from` clause, so it is not updatable.  It is a read-only view.  I am not aware that this was changed in 2012.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, got any suggestions on how to go about it? The reason I need a view is because I need a unique key between a field in CheckUser/ CheckCompany and another field in one of the tables I will be joining with. Or perhaps I am going about it all wrong and should not be using views at all? The other option would be to combine these two tables into a Check table, however I would still need to somehow ensure uniqueness between a field in Check and a field in a second table.

Comment: @user3800174 . . . Can you create the updatable view without the join and then use another join to bring in that information?  Another option is to use an `instead of update` trigger on the view.

Answer (score 9):

You can work around this by adding an ["instead of" trigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) to the view and update the underlying tables instead.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue, to resolve the issue I follow the following steps

1. Create table it does not available

[image]

2. Create View against Table

[image]

Now If you try to insert or update records via View it will give a error "*Update or insert of view or function failed because it contains a derived or constant field*"

3. To Resolve this error, need to create Trigger for the above view

[image]

4. Try to insert / update records via View

[image]

Comment: Please replace your images with text. It is not searchable, copyable, or screen-readable.